# angularjs error: 'idController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm running a Rails 4.2 application with angular 1.3.14 from this [gem](https://github.com/hiravgandhi/angularjs-rails).  I'm running your basic angular tutorial setup - I'm not even at the point where I'm trying to pass in Rails data.  I just want to spit out a list of ids.

Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'idController' is not a function, got undefined

**application.js** in assets pipeline

```
//= require angular
//= require angular_id
```

**This is my javascript, angular_id.js:**

```
(function(angular) {

function idController($scope) {
  $scope.ids = [1,2];
}

var nctIdEditorApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
nctIdEditorApp.controller('idController', ['$scope', idController]);


})(angular);
```

**This is my html (in haml):**

```
%section{"ng-app"=>"myApp"}
  %thead
    %tr
      %th ID
  %table{"ng-controller" => "idController"}
    %tr{"ng-repeat" => "id in ids"}
      %td
        %mark
          {{ id }}
```

Comment: Everything here is fine. This means that your script isn't included in the page, or something got mangled in minification, but there's nothing here that should have a problem being minified. You are missing a semi-colon.. doubt that matters.

Comment: Is your javascript somehow executed afterwards (after some asynchronous call) or is it loaded and executed right away?

Comment: If do 'view source' on the localhost, I see: <script src="/assets/angular.js?body=1"></script><script src="/assets/angular_editor.js?body=1"></script> so the code is being loaded after the angular js library is.  So then everything that angular needs is being loaded?

Comment: Oops, as it turned out, it was a namespace conflict.  I also had <html ng-app=""> in my top level html tag (due to googling various incomplete tutorials).  Once I got rid of that, then it was fine.